# Total changing flux in Faraday's law of induction

Tags: induction

To clarify my question, I made the illustration below, assuming I understood the Faraday-Lenz law:

[image]

Above a copper loop theoretically stays in parallel between the plates A and B.

The magnetic field ***B*** hence the flux between the plates A and B is continuously increased.

The copper loop circulates a current such that to oppose the increasing flux.

Above I showed the directions of increasing flux and self generated opposing flux.

My question is, will the total changing flux always be zero no matter the conductor is perfect or not?

If the applied flux was constant(not varying by time) the total flux would be non zero.

But in case the flux is increasing, will the total changing flux be zero?

Answer (score 1):

The conductor is a loop of wire hence it has self inductance. Do not lose sight of that because, ultimately, this means the net flux can never be cancelled to zero.

So, imagine the loop were opened and the voltage measured. With a steady rising external field, the voltage induced is constant because of the rate of change of flux being constant.

Now with the loop closed and taking into account the loops self inductance, the current flow is a ramp (because of the constant voltage and inductance ignoring DC resistance) that produces an opposing ramping magnetic field inside the coil but an increaded magnetic field outside the coil and local to it: -

[image]

The two fields cannot cancel else there would be no induced voltage to create the counteracting magnetic field. The net effect is no change to the average flux density of the external B field.

Comment: Let me ask this way: Consider the famous formula e = - d(phi)/dt. In this formula is d(phi) "the change in applied flux through the loop" or "total flux change through the loop" (where "total flux change" = increasing flux change-opposing flux change in time) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow precisely your question?

Comment: Lets say the amount of "applied magnetic flux through the loop" increased per second is M. And lets say the "induced loop current's counter opposing flux" amount is N per second. Will the emf = -dM/dt or -d(M-N)/dt ?

Comment: it can be a loop with open end where one can measure the emf

Comment: I think I see where you are coming from - you think that if the flux through the centre of the loop decreases (due to loop current) there must be less induced voltage hence less ramping current hence the flux through the centre rises again - is this where you are heading?

Comment: I think so.  When one says "The change in flux through the centre of the loop". If by that we mean the total change then I think it is "the change in applied flux -(minus) the change in opposing flux due to loop current". But in Faraday's law equation that change is implicit. I don't know it is the total change or the change in applied field. So since you say they are not equal I assume the opposing field change is too small comparing to the applied field change./ ?

Comment: OK, the flux decreases through the centre of the loop due to the induced voltage creating a ramping current but outside the loop, and local to the loop, the flux increases because the secondary current lines of flux are surrounding the coil turns and have to turn back on themselves. This means the induced voltage stays constant.

Comment: In other words, the ramping flux that generates the constant induced voltage remains constantly ramping. What you have to get your head around is that the presense of a short on the coil and the resulting re-shaping of the lines of flux (less in the middle and more around the outside) produces the same induced voltage.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is totally rewritten due the comments and the edits in the question. My answer is for this question:

[image]

The answer:

When speaking or writing about some specific flux one should allways specify

- the surface (real material surface or imagined) over which the flux is calculated.
- which currents or other vector curls of the magnetic field or radiowaves are taken into the account

Some quesses due no specification:

- The flux is calculated through the same circular interior of your copper loop between A and B regardless is that copper loop actually placed or not
- your system behind A and B has the same vector curls for the magnetic field generation regardless is the copper loop actually placed or not. No radiowaves are taken into the account.
- You are not taking into the flux the effect of the induced current in the ring when you write that the flux is continuously increasing

With these very heavy and unjustified assumptions I answer that the total sum flux of all present causes is some amount smaller than it would be if there were no closed copper loop placed.

The behind A and B generated part of the total flux is partially cancelled by the current that is induced to the loop. The current is finite due the resistance of copper and I assumed that the magnetic field generation is not disturbed  by the current in the loop. Especially I assumed that there's no control system that keeps the flux constantly increasing in the same way regardless the existence of the copper loop altough you wrote "the flux between A and B is continuously increased"

The current in the copper loop is generated by the induced emf. That emf is = the negative of the change velocity of the flux. That flux must be calculated as the sum of the flux caused by the induced current and the flux caused by the system behind A and B.

You can see the last claim in the circuit theory. There into a loop induced emf has two components. they are:

- the emf caused by the loop inductance and the current in the loop
- the emf caused by the mutual inducrances and the currents in other loops

Offtopic:

It would have been much easier to write. "You wrote continuously increasing flux. So the flux increases, it's not constant. It's just as you wrote. It's growing"

Comment: You got the heart of my question "The induced current cancels the flux partially" So in Faraday's law equation e = -d(phi) / dt; is d(phi)  "the change in applied flux -(minus) the change in opposing flux due to loop current"? yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

You ask "will the total changing flux always be zero no matter the conductor is perfect or not?".

For clarity, I'm going to assume:

- you are asking about the flux inside the coil
- that the applied magnetic field is always uniform (and constantly increasing) at the surface of the two plates, irrespective of what is happening with the coil.

Given these assumptions, consider the limit cases, then normal conductors:

**Loop is made of perfect insulator**

In this case there will be zero current flowing in the "wire", and the uniform field will increase with no modification.

**Loop is made of a perfect super-conductor**

In this case the induced current in the loop will increase to exactly cancel the increasing applied field.  The applied field will still increase (because that is how we are defining the problem), but the flux lines that would have gone through the center of the coil are expelled, and instead will divert round the outside, making the applied field non-uniform round the coil.

There will be zero flux lines going through the middle of the coil, and it will stay that way as we are considering a perfect superconductor (no critical field strength).

This expulsion of all magnetic fields is the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect).

**Loop is made of normal conductive material**

In between the two cases, we have practical circuits, where the resistance of the coil will mean that any induced current decays, so the total current in the loop will be insufficient to fully expel the applied field.

For a fixed resistance coil (and ignoring overheating, temperature dependence, etc), and with a constantly increasing field, the rate of flux increase in the middle of the coil will be in between the two limit cases, and be a fixed fraction of the applied field's increase.  The rest of the flux will be diverted round the outside of the coil.

If the field stopped increasing, then the current in the coil would decay to zero, and the field would again become uniform.

Answer (score 0):

The case where the resistance of the loop is infinite, and where the resistance of the loop is \$0\$ have been adequately discussed in another answer. This answer will deal only withe the case where there is some finite (non-zero) resistance.

The total flux through the loop is the sum of the applied flux and the reaction flux. (Assuming the applied flux is perpendicular to the loop.)

$$\Phi_{total}=\Phi_{applied} + \Phi_{reaction}$$

The rate of change in the total flux is associated with an induced EMF around the loop.

$$\mathscr{E}=-\frac{d\Phi_{total}}{dt} =-\Phi_{total}'$$

The induced EMF causes a current to flow around the loop that is inversely proportional to the electrical resistance around the loop.

$$I=\frac{\mathscr{E}}{R}$$

Solving for \$\mathscr{E}\$ gives

$$\mathscr{E}=IR$$

and thus

$$\Phi_{total}'= -IR$$

The current through the loop creates the reaction flux that is inversely proportional to the magnetic reluctance associated with the loop.

$$\Phi_{reaction} = \frac{I}{\mathscr{R_m}}$$

Solving for \$I\$ gives

$$I=\Phi_{reaction}\mathscr{R}_m$$

and thus

$$\Phi_{total}' = -\Phi_{reaction}R\mathscr{R}_m$$

Substitution gives

$$\Phi_{total}' = (\Phi_{applied}-\Phi_{total})R\mathscr{R}_m$$

We will define the constant \$\lambda\$ as

$$\lambda = R\mathscr{R}_m$$

If \$R\$ is measured in ohms and the \$\mathscr{R}_m\$ is measured in turns per henry, (and if we assume the number of turns is 1), then \$\lambda\$ has the units \$1/sec\$.

Our equation is now

$$\Phi_{total}' = (\Phi_{applied}-\Phi_{total})\lambda$$

or

$$\Phi_{total}' + \lambda\Phi_{total} = \lambda\Phi_{applied}$$

The transfer function from \$\Phi_{applied}\$ to \$\Phi_{total}\$ is

$$F(s) = \frac{\lambda}{s+\lambda}$$

---

**A particular solution**

> Lets say the amount of "applied magnetic flux through the loop" increased per second is M.

Assuming that at time \$t= 0\$, \$\Phi_{applied}=\Phi_{total}=0\$, and for times \$t>0\$, \$ \Phi_{applied}(t)=Mt\$ we have

$$\Phi_{total} = \frac{M(\lambda t-1)}{\lambda} + \frac{Me^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda}$$

which plots as

[image]

Here, the orange line is \$\Phi_{applied}\$ and the blue line is \$\Phi_{total}\$. As \$t\$ increases, \$\Phi_{total}\$ approaches an asymptote parallel to \$\Phi_{applied}\$.

$$\Phi_{total} \underset{t_\uparrow}{\longrightarrow} \Phi_{applied} - \frac{M}{\lambda}$$

Now let's assume we have a circular loop of #12 AWG copper wire, 31.4 cm long. (i.e. it forms a circle with 10 cm diameter).

According to [this calculator](https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/ind1calc.html), the magnetic reluctance associated with this loop is 1/(0.249 uH) = 4.016 \$MH^{-1}\$ (the inverse of inductance when there is only a single turn).

According to [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance) the resistance of 31.4 cm of #12 AWG copper wire (2.052 mm diameter) is 1.624\$m\Omega\$.

This gives us a \$\lambda\$ value of

$$\lambda = 4.016\times 10^6 \times 1.625\times 10^{-3} = 6.522 \times 10^3 \text{sec}^{-1}$$

Depending upon your point of view, one might say that the total flux approaches its asymptote line fairly quickly.

If the applied magnetic flux is increasing at a rate of, say 1 mWb/sec, when the total magnetic flux nears its asymptote line, it will lag the applied magnetic flux by

$$\frac{M}{\lambda} = \frac{1 mWb/sec}{6522 /sec} = 0.153 uWb$$

So, the total flux will be very nearly the applied flux.

Of course, if one chooses different geometries, different conductive materials, and different rates of flux change, the results will be different. However, I think it is safe to say that if one's time scale of interest is not fairly short, the applied magnetic flux will approximate the total magnetic flux.